# Clarification Array Pointers in Cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I am currently picking up on C++ and I just want clarification about a thing I came up with.

Suppose I have some array `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};`.
Is `int *arr_p = arr` the same as `int *arr_p = &arr[0]`?
As far as I understood, the `arr` is pointing to the first element and therefore has the type `int *`, whereas `&arr` is a pointer to the whole array with a different type.
Same adress, different type.

It feels somewhat illogical how the pointers are behaving, but I think I am getting more and more comfortable with them.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: _Is int *arr_p = arr the same as int *arr_p = &arr[0]?_ Simple answer is yes. But your following sentence seems to be unrelated. In `&arr[0]` you're not checking the address of `arr` with `&`, you're checking the address of `arr[0]` which is an `int`.

Comment: You're right. `arr` could decay to pointer pointing to the 1st element of the array. BTW `&arr` is a pointer to the array with type `int(*)[3]`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I just got lost with the "decaying" process and therefore the difference between arr and &arr[0] (and of course &arr)

Comment: One more question:
Why is it decaying to `&arr[0]` and not `&arr`?

Comment: It's important to remeber that postfix operators are always higher precedence than prefix, so `&arr[0]` is equivalent to `&(arr[0])` and not `(&arr)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to an array of three ints can be written as follows,

```
int arr[3] = {2, 4, 6};

int (*Parr)[3] = arr;
```

if you dereference Parr you can actually access the whole array as opposed to the first element of the array. hence you can write,

```
std::cout << (*Parr)[2] << std::endl;
```

This will allow you to access the last element in the array (6). It is important to remember to use precedence by using a parenthesis to dereference and use indexing.